# Busca em Largura e Profundidade num grafo

Tags: java, grafo

Eu preciso implementar um sistema de visitas, e a busca em Largura (grafos).

Como proceder?
[EDIT]
Eu hostaria de saber a melhor forma de fazer com que esse algorítimo funcione também para Grafo, pois atualmente só está funcionando especificamente para arvores sem direção.
Gostaria que alguém me mostrasse a forma mais "correta" de implementar o um método para a busca em largura, e um método que demonstre quais nós foram percorridos.

O fiz:

```
public class GrafoMatriz {
    int[][] grafo;
    int[] visitas;
    int nVertices;
    int[] profundidade;

    public void getMatriz(String file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";

        line = br.readLine();
        nVertices = Integer.parseInt(line);
        grafo = new int[nVertices][nVertices];
        visitas = new int[nVertices];

        line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            String[] pares = line.split(" ");
            grafo[Integer.parseInt(pares[0])][Integer.parseInt(pares[1])] = 1;
            // matriz[Integer.parseInt(pares[1])][Integer.parseInt(pares[0])] =
            // 1;
            line = br.readLine();

        }
        profundidade = new int[nVertices];
        br.close();
        // return matriz;
    }

    public void imprimeMatriz() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nVertices; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nVertices; j++) {
                System.out.print(grafo[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n--------------------\n");
    }

    public void zeraMatriz() {
        for (int i = 0; i < grafo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grafo[i].length; j++) {
                grafo[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void geraListaVisitas(int no1, int no2) {
        zeraLista();
        eAlcancavel(no1, no2);
        imprimeLista();

    }

    public void eAlcancavel(int no1, int no2) {
        visitas[no1] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < visitas.length; i++) {
            if (grafo[no1][i] == 1) {
                eAlcancavel(i, no2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimeLista() {
        for (int i = 0; i < visitas.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(visitas[i] + " ");

        }
    }

    public void zeraLista() {
        for (int i = 0; i < visitas.length; i++) {
            visitas[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public void profundidade(int x){
        profundidade[x]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Busca em profundidade usa pilha/recursão direta. Busca em largura faz as buscas através de uma fila

Comment: Desculpe, vou editar a pergunta.